# renaming existing .csv files within a folder

Tags: r

I have a folder called "data" which contains .csv files with data from individual participants. The filename of each of the participants .csv file is an alphanumeric code assigned to them (which is also stored in a column within the .csv called "ppt"), plus the word "data" and the hour they completed the study (e.g., 13 = 1pm).

So for example, the filename of this participant .csv would be "3ht2phfu7data13.csv"

| ppt | choice | error |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3ht2phfu7 | d | 0 |
| 3ht2phfu7 | d | 0 |
| 3ht2phfu7 | k | 1 |

whilst the filename of this participant .csv would be "3a5tzoirpdata15.csv"

| ppt | choice | error |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3a5tzoirp | k | 1 |
| 3a5tzoirp | d | 0 |
| 3a5tzoirp | k | 1 |

These are just 2 examples, but there are 60 individual .csv files in total.

I am trying to rename each of these files, so that instead of containing the participant alphanumeric code, each participant is assigned a number ranging from 1 to 60. So for example, instead of an individual participant file being named "3ht2phfu7data.csv", I'd like it to be named "1data.csv", and for the ppt column to also change to be "1" for each row (to match the new filename), rather than the "3ht2phfu7" that it currently is.

Then going along with another example, for "3a5tzoirpdata.csv" to be named "2data.csv" and for the ppt column to also change to be "2" for each row (to match the new filename). And then so on with the remaining 58 .csv files in the folder.

I have tried the following code, no error message appears but it is not producing amended .csv files. Any help would be really appreciated

```
files <- list.files(path = 'data/', pattern = '*.csv', full.names = TRUE)

sapply(files, function(file){
  x <- read.csv(file)
  x$participant <- c(1:60)
  write.csv(paste0(x, "data", file))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea, but there were some problems in the `sapply`.
You can't iterate over filenames if you want to assign a consecutive number.
In the `write.csv` the object to write to file was missing. For the file name we first have to extract the file's directory with `dirname` and then add the desired filename.

```r
files <- list.files(path = 'data/', pattern = '*.csv', full.names = TRUE)

sapply(1:length(files), function(i){
  # read file
  x <- read.csv(files[i])
  # change participant code to consecutive number
  x$participant <- i
  write.csv(x, paste0(dirname(files[i]), "/", i, "data.csv"), row.names = F, quote = F)

})
```

Comment: Thank you! this is a really helpful and clear explanation. Although when I run this code, the error: "Error in 1:nrow(files) : argument of length 0" appears

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake: it should have used `length` instead of `nrow` in the `sapply` function.

Comment: Oh I see. Now when I run the code this is appearing: "Error in file[i] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" - I will restart R and try again

Comment: there were two typos in sapply. Should be `files` and not `file`.

Comment: should I be adding anything after dirname? with typos fixed "Error in dirname(files[i], "/", i, "data.csv") : unused arguments ("/", i, "data.csv")" now appears

Comment: Sorry, I should have tested it before. The brackets were misplaced. Edited the answer and tested it. Also added `row.name = F` and `quote = F` to prevent writing rownames and putting all values in quotes in the file. Should work now

Comment: No need to apologise at all. That's great - it works now! :) thanks so much for making that so clear. Just wondering if you know if it would be possible to output somewhere / store which of the files are replaced with which number (e.g., that '3ht2phfu7' was replaced with '1', '3a5tzoirp' was replaced with '2', etc) - although it's not mega important

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230435/discussion-between-pavlopavlin-and-abc-95).